# Does this algorithm generate a uniform distribution on the unit disc (deterministic RNG)?

Tags: python, algorithm

Consider the following algorithm:

```
r = 2
while r >= 1:
    x = -1 + 2 * random.random()
    y = -1 + 2 * random.random()
    r = x * x + y * y
```

Now if my research is correct, python's random module uses the system time as the initial seed (let us consider this to be uniformly distributed) and after that generates a deterministic sequence of numbers using the [mersenne twister algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) where every call to `random.random()` will result in a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

When the algorithm terminates, the point `(x,y)` should be somewhere on the unit disc. Due to the limits of floating-point arithmetic, we can of course not obtain every point inside the unit disc, but *among those we can obtain, will this algorithm result in a uniform distribution?*

Or, equivalently, *will this algorithm return every point obtainable with the same probability?*

I considered posting this to math.se, but since the question is closely related to python and algorithms, I assumed StackOverflow to be more appropriate.

Now my intuition tells me the distribution is not uniform. Consider a seed `s1` for which the point initially generated is not inside the unit disc, the algorithm will then deterministically generate a new point `(x,y)` (let us assume this point to be inside the unit circle) and terminate. Now I would assume there is a seed `s2` for which the point initially generated equals the point `(x,y)` generated by `s1`.

Apparently, I can generate `(x,y)` by using at least 2 different seeds, of which one actually generated a different point outside the unit circle first. Now since the unit disc does not contain half the area of `[-1,1) x [-1,1)`, I would conclude that not every point is generated by the same number of seeds, which would mean that for uniformly distributed seeds, the points returned are not chosen uniformly.

To prevent this from becoming an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please consider above paragraph to be part of my research and not the central point of this question. The actual question is the one printed in *italics*.

Comment: Aren't you just asking if `random.random()` is uniformly distributed? That's a programming question. The rest does not appear to be.

Comment: You're talking about the unit disc, not the unit circle.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, the actual point is that if I have a condition under which I "re-roll", will the fact that `random()` is deterministic after the first call have any influence on the distribution of the result. It certaintly would not if `random()` was generated using actual randomness.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks, I am going to correct that!

Comment: @chepner I am absolutely aware of this, this is how I would have done it in the first place, the algorithm in question is not mine however.

Comment: @chepner: r can be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @EricDuminil I was still working off the original question that asked about the unit circle.

Comment: Okay. I wasn't sure at first either, but the code made it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will this algorithm return every point obtainable with the same probability?

Technically no, but a long RNG period essentially neutralizes the effect, and the exact probabilities of specific points aren't what we care about when sampling from continuous distributions anyway. Rejection sampling this way should be fine.

Your analysis is correct, so far as the fact that if seed `s` results in a rejection and the result from `s'` is used instead, then both seeds produce the same output. However, for a long enough RNG period, many seeds will naturally correspond to the same output, and (assuming good statistical properties of the underlying RNG) this doubling effect will be spread near-uniformly across all possible outputs, so even the distribution over individual output points won't be compromised. Python's default RNG is Mersenne Twister, and the period of that is huge.

Even if the above didn't hold, we wouldn't care. We're already accepting a fundamental non-uniformity in the fact that we literally can't even represent, let alone generate, almost all points in the unit disc. If some of the individual points we *can* generate get a higher weight than others, that doesn't really matter, as long as it doesn't introduce any important statistical biases. If points on the left got a higher weight than points on the right, we'd care. If points in one statistically-indistinguishable-from-uniform set get a higher weight than points in a different statistically-indistinguishable-from-uniform set, it's not a big deal.

Finally, if seed `s` gets rejected and seed `s'` gets used in its place, that's two seeds that would give the same output, but we don't actually see that output twice, because we advanced past both seeds. If we're generating a sequence of points this way, without other intervening uses of the RNG, this mostly eliminates the effect you're worried about.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could elaborate on that "no"

Comment: @curious: I've added some elaboration.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense to me. I did finally decide to ask this on math.se to get an answer independent of the usual restrictions in computing. I know that no pseudo-RNG out there would ever produce a completely uniform distribution, let alone the collisions implied by that. The point of this cancelling out the bias in the distribution is however very much appreciated. I think this passes as the answer to the question in context of programming.

Answer (score 1):

My point of view might be too simplistic, but you basically generate points inside the bounding box between (-1,-1) and (1,1), and remove every point outside the unit disk. You don't shuffle anything, you don't move any point, you just cut a shape into another one.

The points inside the unit disk will be just as uniformly distributed as those in the square. It doesn't mean they are uniformly distributed. Just that your analysis shouldn't be influenced by the `while r >= 1:`.

Here are 1E6 points out of your algorithm :

[image]

Comment: ...and i was just about to ask you to visualize that. great timing!

Comment: The problem I see with this is that the points are not placed independently of each other. Sure, every re-run of the program generates a new seed and is thus perfectly random, but after the initial point is discarded, another one is generated and this one depends on the previous on via the mersenne twister algorithm.

Comment: Considering your edit, I am not suggesting the difference will be big enough to be noticable by the human eye.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is <strike>no</strike> yes. This algorithm will <strike>not</strike> provide uniform distribution inside a unit circle. <strike>The reason is that some of your samples will get outside of the circle</strike>. In order to get the <strike>mathematically correct</strike> predictable uniform distribution you have to use polar coordinates and for such coordinates your code sample should do this:

```
def get_random_point_in_unit_circle():
    theta = random.random() * ( 2 * math.pi )
    r = math.sqrt(random.random())
    x = r * math.cos( theta )
    y = r * math.sin( theta )
    return (x, y)
```

edit:

So my answer is not entirely correct, thanks for pointing that out. In terms of the probability your function provides uniform distribution as the probability of getting the sample within the area is constant. The drawback of solution with rejection is unpredictability.

Comment: As I said in a comment, I am aware of this method and it would be my preferred style of implementation. However, the proposed algorithm is not mine and I am curious to know if the results would be the same.

Comment: "some of your samples will get outside of the circle" - those get rejected. We don't actually output those.

Comment: Note : `r = math.sqrt(random.random())` is really important. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html

Comment: We also have the re-roll question for this algorithm, it looks like r and theta may not be independent random variables.

Comment: @user2357112 yes you are right, thanks for pointing that - I was more concerned about the unpredictability of the solution with rejection. In terms of the correctness of uniform distribution that doesn't change much as it has been shown by others :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several approximations on top of one another.

Floats are merely an approximation to real numbers.

Python random doesn't even give a correctly rounded random real; it gives a uniform distribution on 0, 1/2^53, 2/2^53, ..., (2^53-1)/2^53 assuming a uniform source.

The source is only approximately uniform because MT states cannot be zero.

Even if the source were uniform random in each particular sample given a true random seed, enough subsequent samples are not independent, because that's how pseudorandom generators work.

Given that the seed is finite, it's impossible to generate uniform distributions that have a number of outcomes that does not divide the size of seed space. This is almost certainly the case for your distribution.